# invert blend mode in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a `SpriteKit` game and have two `SKShapeNodes` and I would like them to have invert blend mode.

What I would like to achieve is when I move the first sprite over the other one, where the shape is overlapped by the second shape, it should have inverted colours, like this image:

[image]

Comment: There is no XOR blendMode unfortunately

Comment: What you can do is use subtract blending,  but you would have to use SKCropNode so that you can place the partially drawn white circle underneath your current circle.  This  will get you a XOR like effect

Comment: Thank you Knight0fDragon, I will give it a try but using SKCropNodes with dynamically drawn shapes takes a lot of resources on older devices.

Comment: hmm, you know, now that I think about it,  try using the inverse color to begin with over white using a subtract blend.  This should get you your original color back.  Then when you hover over something non white,  You should notice an effect (make sure whatever you are hovering goes between the white and the original image